# WPF, C#, Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, imagesource

Пытаюсь осуществить сохранение наименование выбранной фотографии. Вот код привязки:

```
<Image Width="250"
                   Source="{Binding Materials.GetPicture}"
                   Height="250"
                   Name="Picture"/>
```

Все фотографии у меня в bin, чтобы получить их, я прописал в partial сущности такой код:

```
 public partial class Material
{
    public string GetPicture
    {
        get
        {
            return Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/" + Photo;
        }
    }
}
```

Так выглядит весь код страницы

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Border BorderThickness="2">
            <Image Width="250"
                   Source="{Binding Materials.GetPicture}"
                   Height="250"
                   Name="Picture"/>
        </Border>
        <Button Content="Выбрать"
                Foreground="White"
                materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="10"
                Margin="0,10,0,0"
                Click="btnSelec_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Width="350">
            <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Наименование"
                     Text="{Binding Materials.Title}"
                     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
            <ComboBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Тип"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Types}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Materials.Type}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                      Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}">
            </ComboBox>
            <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Цена"
                     PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
                     Text="{Binding Materials.Cost}"
                     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
            <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Количество на складе"
                     Text="{Binding Materials.CountInStorage}"
                     PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
                     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
            <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Минимальное количество"
                     Text="{Binding Materials.MinCount}"
                     PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
                     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
            <TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Количество в упаковке"
                     PreviewTextInput="TextBox_PreviewTextInput"
                     Text="{Binding Materials.CountInPackage}"
                     Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"/>
            <ComboBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Единица измерения"
                      Text="{Binding Units}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Materials.Unit}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"
                      Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintComboBox}">
            </ComboBox>
            <Button Content="Сохранить"
                    Foreground="White"
                    materialDesign:ButtonAssist.CornerRadius="10"
                    Margin="0,10,0,0"
                    Click="btnSave_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Я осуществил добавление всех других записей в базу данных, кроме наименование фотографии. Так же сделал так, чтобы выбранная фотография перемещалась в bin файл

```
 OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void btnSelec_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        file.Filter = "Image (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*png;)|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*png;";
        Picture.Source = file.ShowDialog() == true ? Picture.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.FileName)) : null;

    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Materials.ID == 0)
            {
                File.Copy(file.FileName, $"materials\\ {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName).Trim()}", true);
                AppData.db.Material.Add(Materials);
            }
            AppData.db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Данные успешной сохранены.", "Итог операции: УСПЕШНО", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            NavigationService.GoBack();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

Метод: `Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)`
Возвращает имя выбранного элемента, я сделал так:

```
if (Materials.ID == 0)
            {
                File.Copy(file.FileName, $"materials\\ {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName).Trim()}", true);
                Materials.GetPicture = "\\materials\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                AppData.db.Material.Add(Materials);
            }
```

Выходит ошибка о том, что поле `Materials.GetPicture` доступно только для чтения.

Вопрос, как мне сделать так, чтобы наименование фотографии с наименованием папки в bin - сохранялась в базе данных? Я пытаюсь привязать GetPicture к Image.Source но, ничего не выходит.

Comment: `но, ничего не выходит` - это не объяснение проблемы. `Materials.GetPicture доступно только для чтения.` - ну так у него есть только `get`, о каком тогда изменении свойства может идти речь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я просто не знал, как правильно прописать set, надо было просто про get и set прочитать...

```
public partial class Material
{
    public string GetPicture
    {
        get
        {
            return Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"/" + Photo;
        }
        set
        {
            photo = value
        }
    }
}
```